# How to query the last modification date of a file via HTTP on the iPhone using NSHTTPURLResponse?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest

In my iPhone application I need to query the last modification date of an internet `.m4a` file via `HTTP`, but I **DON'T** want to downloading it.

I'm reading Apple's documentation about `NSURLRequest` and `NSHTTPURLResponse`, but it seems to be all related to downloading the file and not querying it first. Maybe I'm wrong.

How can I know the last modification date of a `.m4a` file, via `HTTP`, **WITHOUT** downloading it?

Thanks!

Comment: I really dont think that its possible to query this sort of data without downloading the file, i dont think is doable in iphone or any other sdk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer assumes your server supports it, but what you do is send a "HEAD" request to the file URL and you get back just the file headers. You can then inspect the header called "Last-Modified" which normally has the date format `@"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"`.

Here's some code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) 
{
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
  NSString *lastUpdated = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
  NSDate *lastUpdatedServer = [fileDateFormatter dateFromString:lastUpdated];

  if (([localCreateDate earlierDate:lastUpdatedServer] == localCreateDate) && lastUpdatedServer) 
  {
    NSLog(@"local file is outdated: %@ ", localPath);
    isLatest = NO;
  } else {
    NSLog(@"local file is current: %@ ", localPath);
  }

} else {
  NSLog(@"Failed to get server response headers");
}
```

Of course, you probably want this to be done asynchronously in the background, but this code should point you in the right direction.

Best Regards.

Comment: Sure! It helped me a lot and now I'll work to make it asynchronously!

Comment: Of course if the server doesn't support HEAD, you can simply cancel the connection as soon as you've received the response

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but in my case the server does support HEAD.

Answer (score 4):

The method below performs a `HEAD` request to only fetch the header with a `Last-Modified` field and converts it to `NSDate` object.

```
- (NSDate *)lastModificationDateOfFileAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    // Set the HTTP method to HEAD to only get the header.
    request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                          returningResponse:&amp;response
                                      error:&amp;error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return nil;
    }
    else if([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)])
    {
        NSDictionary *headerFields = [response allHeaderFields];
        NSString *lastModification = [headerFields objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];

        return [formatter dateFromString:lastModification];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You should run this method asynchronously in the background so the main thread is not blocked waiting for the response. This can be easily done using couple of lines of `GCD`.

The code below performs a call to fetch the last modification date in a background thread, and call a completion block on the main thread when the date is retrieved.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    // Perform a call on the background thread.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourFileURL"];

    NSDate *lastModifDate = [self lastModificationDateOfFileAtURL:url];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        // Do stuff with lastModifDate on the main thread.
    });
});
```

I wrote an article about this here:

[**Getting last modification date of a file on the server using Objective-C.**](http://stunningco.de/2014/03/26/getting-a-last-modification-date-of-a-file-on-the-server-using-objective-c/)